# How do I read a json file into python?

Tags: python, json, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to JSON and Python, any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

I read about json.loads but am confused

How do I read a file into Python using json.loads?

Below is my JSON file format:

```
{
        "header": {
        "platform":"atm"
        "version":"2.0"
       }
        "details":[
       {
        "abc":"3"
        "def":"4"
       },
       {
        "abc":"5"
        "def":"6"
       },
       {
        "abc":"7"
        "def":"8"
       }    
      ]
    }
```

My requirement is to read the values of all `"abc"` `"def"` in details and add this is to a new list like this `[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8)]`. The new list will be used to create a spark data frame.

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: what is your question and what did you try?

Comment: How can I achieve the above in python. I read about json.loads but am confused :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the file, and get a filehandle:

```
fh = open('thefile.json')
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Then, pass the file handle into json.load():  (don't use loads - that's for strings)

```
import json
data = json.load(fh)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load

From there, you can easily deal with a python dictionary that represents your json-encoded data.

```
new_list = [(detail['abc'], detail['def']) for detail in data['details']]
```

Note that your JSON format is also wrong.   You will need comma delimiters in many places, but that's not the question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to understand your question as best as I can, but it looks like it was formatted poorly.

First off your json blob is not valid json, it is missing quite a few commas. This is probably what you are looking for:

```
{
    "header": {
        "platform": "atm",
        "version": "2.0"
    },
    "details": [
        {
            "abc": "3",
            "def": "4"
        },
        {
            "abc": "5",
            "def": "6"
        },
        {
            "abc": "7",
            "def": "8"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now assuming you are trying to parse this in python you will have to do the following.

```
import json

json_blob = '{"header": {"platform": "atm","version": "2.0"},"details": [{"abc": "3","def": "4"},{"abc": "5","def": "6"},{"abc": "7","def": "8"}]}'
json_obj = json.loads(json_blob)

final_list = []

for single in json_obj['details']:
    final_list.append((int(single['abc']), int(single['def'])))

print(final_list)
```

This will print the following: [(3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]

Comment: As FlipMcF is mentioned, if you are reading from a file, json.load() will handle file like reads. This is mentioned in the python docs.