# How to read in .json file in python?

Tags: python, json

I want to read in only "text" part of the json file below. That is: HAPPY NEW YEAR! 
....Senator Schumer, more than a year longer than any other Administration in history. These are people who have been approved by committees and all others, yet Schumer continues to hold them back from serving their Country! Very Unfair!

then train the words in my RNN model, what should I do to get text and delete the others?

json file:

```
[{"source": "Twitter for iPhone", "id_str": "1079888205351145472", "text": "HAPPY NEW YEAR! ", "created_at": "Mon Dec 31 23:53:06 +0000 2018", "retweet_count": 33548, "in reply to user id str": null, "favorite_count": 136012, "is_retweet": false},
 {"source": "Twitter for iPhone", "id_str": "1079830268708556800", "text": "....Senator Schumer, more than a year longer than any other Administration in history. These are people who have been approved by committees and all others, yet Schumer continues to hold them back from serving their Country! Very Unfair!", "created_at": "Mon Dec 31 20:02:52 +0000 2018", "retweet_count": 17456, "in reply to user id str": "25073877", "favorite_count": 65069, "is_retweet": false}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read a json file into python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419753/how-do-i-read-a-json-file-into-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `list` comprehension:

```
[element['text'] for element in data]
```

You can also use `map` in conjunction with `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

list(map(itemgetter('text'), data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
text_data = ""

with open(file_path) as file_obj:
    json_data = json.load(file_obj)
    for single_json in json_data:
        print(single_json["text"])
        text_data += single_json["text"]

print(text_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as reading the file and concatenating the relevant section of the parsed json object. I'm assuming you need the whole thing as a single string and not a list of strings.

```
import json
with open('file.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    text = "".join(d['text'] for d in data)

print(text)
```

With `file.json` being your data file & `text` being the extracted string.